# regexp to break text into array by spaces, punctuation marks, linebreaks

Tags: php, regex

I need to break texts into array by spaces, punctuation marks, linebreaks. Here is the sample text:

> A man’s jacket is of green color.
>   He – the biggest star in modern history – rides bikes very fast (230 km per hour). How is it possible?! What kind of bike is he using?
>   The semi-automatic gear of his bike, which is quite expensive, significantly helps to reach that speed. Some (or maybe many) claim that he is the fastest in the world! “I saw him ride the bike!” Mr. John Deer speaks. “The speed he sets is 133.78 kilometers per hour,” which sounds incredible; sounds deceiving.

I've already got the [regex that does that](https://eval.in/66333):

```
preg_split('/(?<=\s)|(?<=\w)(?=[.,:;!?()-])|(?<=[.,!()?\x{201C}])(?=[^ ])/u', $text);
```

But currently it splits the following `semi-automatic` into two words, while it has to remain one. If there are spaces aside of dash, as in `semi - automatic`, then this should be three words. I don't quite understand how this regexp is working so any help is appreciated.

The second problem is that if the text contains line breaks, it catches line breaks but also creates redundant element. See the [example](https://eval.in/66333) - elements [8] and [9]. Element [8] is redundant. How can I work around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested the following.

First lets change the regex:

```
/[.,:;!?()\s]|(?<=\s)-(?=\s)/u
```

Explained:

`[.,:;!?()\s]` - split on punctuation

`|(?<=\s)-(?=\s)` - (alternate) split on `-` that has a space either side of `-`

Next, do an `array_filter()` on the result, removing empty|false elements

EDIT:

To keep punctuation use:

```
/(?=[.,:;!?()\s])|(?<=\s)-(?=\s)/u
```

I just surrounded the character class with a lookahead

EDIT 2:

```
/\s|(?=[.,:;!?)])|(?<=\s[("])|(?<=\s)-(?=\s)/u
```

EDIT 3:

```
\s|(?<=\s)-(?=\s)|(?<=\w)(?=[.,:;!?])|(?<=[.,"!()?\x{201C}])(?=[^ ])
```

EDIT 4:

```
\s|(?<=\s)-(?=\s)|(?<=\w)(?=[.,:;!?)])|(?<=[.,"!()?\x{201C}])(?=[^ ])
```

**EXPLAINED:**

Oh my my, me head wasn't in the game today. Your regex was nearly there, just a mod or two was needed so here is the final regex.

```
/\s|(?<=\w)(?=[.,:;!?)])|(?<=[.,"!()?\x{201C}])/u
```

Note: lookarounds just match something, they consume zero characters, hence the 'zero width assertion' term you may come across. If we didn't use lookarounds, the regex engine would match on that character and remove it from the matches. The pipe meta character `|` is an `OR`, in regex terms an `alternate` pattern.

`\s` - match a white space character. We don't need this in a lookaround as we want to remove it anyway.

`(?<=\w)(?=[.,:;!?)])` - OR match with a positive lookbehind for a word character `\w` followed by a positive lookahead of any of the following punctuation characters `.,:;!?)`.

`(?<=[.,"!()?\x{201C}])` - OR match with a positive lookbehind for the following punctuation characters `.,"!()?\x{201C}`. The `\x{201C}` is a left double quotation mark (unicode double byte character).

`u` - modifier to allow utf-8 characters like `\x{201C}`

In your original regex the `(?=[^ ])` at the end is redundant so I removed it. It could have been written `(?!\s)` which is the same, a negative lookahead for a single white space character.

So you'd use `preg_split()` like:

```
$return = preg_split('/\s|(?<=\w)(?=[.,:;!?)])|(?<=[.,"!()?\x{201C}])/u', $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)
```

Comment: Thanks, but you regexp just as _Casimir_'s leaves punctuation marks out.

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand you wanted to keep punctuation. I've updated the answer, see how it goes now

Comment: Thanks, that's close :). However, still there are some things to improve: "(230" should be two elements - "(" and "230", quotes should also be separated - `“I` should be two elements `“` and "I". And it also seems that linebreak is not separated but is paired with words that follow line break - "He", "The" in [this example](https://eval.in/66956). Is that possible to fix it?

Comment: @Maximus sure. I had to test this time, check 2nd edit. There still maybe issues, as you may not have given all scenarios.

Comment: Thanks for you efforts! I've definitely not expressed requirements clearly, I assumed that one would explore the regexp that I already have. Still the issues are present. `“` and `”` should be separated, currently they are still part of some words and punctuation marks - `,”` and `!”` and others. Plus where I expected the linebreak - array[8] and array[43] - ord() returns 0, which is NULL.

Comment: You can't match every scenario as there will be situations like `hi number 4.29 is a great number`, so will it be `4.29` or `4` and `.` and `29` etc etc etc. At the end it's a impossible task because the english language is the most complex, and grammer/slang/colloquialism etc come into play. I don't see you achieving what you want entirely if not ever. Medium ground, added with a parser :)

Comment: :)... the  regex I cited in my question [does almost what I want](https://eval.in/66333) except that it breaks `semi-automatic` into two words and creates redundant spaces before line-breaks. I can illiminate redundant spaces, so only the problem with splitted word remains. Do you think we can incorporate this part of your regex `(?<=\s)-(?=\s)` (which I assume looks for words like `semi-automatic`) into the original regex?

Comment: Thanks a lot! With the 3rd edition we'are almost there :). I'll set your answer as accepted, since you've done an amazing job. However, if you'll have time there is one issue which was OK in 2nd edit and is not in 3rd - this mark `)` should be separated, with 3rd edit it's not, you can see it in `many)` and `hour)`.

Comment: @Maximus my bad, forgot to add `)` back into regex, updated answer :)

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you very much! Do you think you could find time to explain how the regex in edit 4 works in details? I'd like to understand it so that I can modify it when needed without creating a new topic similar to this one :)

Comment: Thank you so much for the eloborate explanation! When I tested your regex in `eval.in`, the 8th element had `ord()` equal to `0`, which I assumed I could treat as `linefeed` - `ord(10)`. However, when I run the regex in my application, all `ord(0)` elements didn't appear in resulting array. Do you know why that can be? I definitely need line feeds and my original regexp adds them to the resulting array.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
preg_split('/[^\PP.-]|(?<=\s)-(?=\s)|\s+|\.(?!\d)/u', $str, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Comment: Thanks, but your regexp leaves out punctuation marks and line breaks. I need them to stay in the resulting array.